# How to pop to rootview controll without using popToRootViewControll method?

Tags: iphone, ios4

How to pop to rootview controll without using popToRootViewControll method because this method does not implement viewDidLoad method of RootViewController???

Comment: There is very little detail here. Can you be a bit more elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take a different approach to solving this problem.

If you have code in the root view controller's `viewDidLoad` method that you want to run again, then that code shouldn't be in the `viewDidLoad` method in the first place. viewDidLoad only runs just after the view controller's view is loaded (usually just once in the lifetime of the view controller). You should probably put that code it in its own method in the view controller, so you can still call it from the `viewDidLoad` method.

To have the code run when you pop to the root view controller, you can call that new method from the root view controller's `viewWillAppearAnimated` method, which gets called each time the view controller's view is about to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "because this method does not implement viewDidLoad method of RootViewController"?

The "viewDidLoad" is called only one time if you don't have memory warning. If you get an memory warning your viewDidLoad method is called again.

You need to implement your logic in "viewWillAppear".

And maybe you should read [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) here you find the `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear` methods